# Satzstruktur durch Konnektoren erkennen

Tags: grammar-identification, conjunction

My friend is learning for the C1 exam and was asking me to help with a question from her textbook(*telc C1 Hochschule / Klett*, p.7). The question is about to recognize the structure of sentences by the application of "Konnektoren". It consists of 4 parts where 1-3 seem clear to me since the meaning of the sentence is changed. I couldn't really figure out the answer to 4 though. One sentence just *seems* wrong to me but I am missing the terminology to explain my assumption on this to her in English.

I read up the Grammar section referenced in the task, but still couldn't come up with an  explanation for 4.

The below text is the task from the textbook.

I marked the "Konnektor" which I think changes the meaning in bold text.

My question is, in task 4, which sentence does not fit into the Konnektor scheme, syntax or meaning of the reference sentence and why? Which is the Konnektor and which grammatical construct does apply here?

---

> Schritt für Schritt zur Lösung
>
> ---
>
> In jedem Text gibt es logische Verbindungen zwischen den einzelnen
> Sätzen und Absätzen. Diese Beziehungen werden durch spezielle Wörter
> zum Ausdruck gebracht, durch sogenannte Konnektoren (z. B. temporale,
> kausale, konzessive Konjunktionen, Adverbien usw.) und Referenzwörter
> (Pronomen, Adverbien und Pronominaladverbien).
>
> Die Struktur eines Textes wird für Sie deutlich, wenn Sie auf diese
> Wörter achten.  Tipp: Siehe Grammatik Seite 116 ff.
>
> Vergleichen Sie die Sätze mit den Auswahloptionen. Jeweils ein Satz
> passt nicht. Kreuzen Sie an. Markieren Sie jeweils das Wort, das die
> Aussage falsch macht.

---

> 1. *Papier und Pappe lassen sich in der Regel problemlos recyceln. Hierdurch verringern sich der Verbrauch an neuem Holz und der Energie-
>    und Wassereinsatz bei der Papierproduktion.*
>
> a) Indem man Papier und Pappe recycelt, verringern sich der Verbrauch
> an neuem Holz und der Energie- und Wassereinsatz bei der
> Papierproduktion.
>
> b) Papier und Pappe kann man recyceln.
> Infolgedessen verringern sich der Verbrauch an neuem Holz und der
> Energie- und Wassereinsatz bei der Papierproduktion.
>
> c) Papier und Pappe sind recycelbar, **weil** sich der Verbrauch an
> neuem Holz und der Energie und Wassereinsatz bei der Papierproduktion
> verringern.

c) *weil* changes the meaning.

---

> 2. *Das Recycling von Glas benötigt deutlich weniger Energie, als wenn Glas neu aus den ursprünglichen Rohstoffen hergestellt wird.*
>
> a) Als Glas aus den ursprünglichen Rohstoffen neu hergestellt wurde,
> **benötigte** man weniger Energie als beim Recycling.
>
> b) Bei der neuen Herstellung von Glas aus den ursprünglichen
> Rohstoffen benötigt man mehr Energie als beim Recycling.
>
> c) Wenn man Glas recycelt, benötigt man nicht mehr Energie als bei der
> neuen Herstellung aus den ursprünglichen Rohstoffen, im Gegenteil.

I think it is a) because **benötigte** is past tense.

---

> 3. *In der Cafeteria gibt es ab sofort Pfandbecher für Kaffee zum Mitnehmen, damit weniger Müll auf dem Campus entsteht.*
>
> a) Es soll weniger Müll auf dem Campus entstehen. Um dieses Ziel zu
> erreichen, gibt es in der Cafeteria ab sofort Pfandbecher für Kaffee
> zum Mitnehmen.
>
> b) **Indem** weniger Müll auf dem Campus entsteht, gibt es ab sofort
> in der Cafeteria Pfandbecher für Kaffee zum Mitnehmen.
>
> c) Zur Senkung der Müllproduktion auf dem Campus gibt es ab sofort in
> der Cafeteria Pfandbecher für Kaffee zum Mitnehmen.

b) **Indem** inverts Kausalität.

---

> 4. *Während sich Glas ohne Qualitätsverlust beliebig oft einschmelzen lässt, sinkt die Qualität des recycelten Kunststoffs.*
>
> a) Glas kann ohne Qualitätsverluste beliebig oft eingeschmolzen
> werden. Dagegen sinkt die Qualität des recycelten Kunststoffs.
>
> b) Im Gegensatz zu Glas, das man ohne Qualitätsverluste beliebig oft
> einschmelzen kann, sinkt die Qualität des recycelten Kunststoffs.
>
> c) Glas ist ohne Qualitätsverluste beliebig oft einzuschmelzen. Im
> Gegenteil dazu sinkt die Qualität des recycelten Kunststoffs.

My guess is c) because **Im Gegenteil** sounds wrong to me.

Comment: The fourth sentence sounds like it is missing at least one word.

Comment: Für mich klingt schon der Ausgangssatz von 4. schräg. Normalerweise wird *während* (wie auch *wohingegen*) für Gegensätze zweier gleichrangiger Dinge benutzt, die als Subjekt auftreten, also etwa: *„Während Glas dies tut, tut Kunststoff jenes.“* Bei 4. stehen allerdings *Glas* und *Qualität* im Gegensatz, was meines Erachtens mindestens ein stilistischer, wenn nicht ein grammatischer Konstruktionsfehler ist.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: Sehe ich inhatlich anders: Glas hat Eigenschaft x (Qualität bleibt), während Kunststoff die Eigenschaft x nicht hat (Qualität sinkt).

Comment: @ShegitBrahm, genau das steht ja da eben nicht, was mich doch erst zum Kommentar veranlasst hat. In Ihrem Satz sind richtigerweise *Glas* und *Kunststoff* die Subjekte, den sie werden miteinander verglichen. Im Ausgangssatz 4. sind aber *Glas* und *Qualität* die Subjekte. Klar versteht man worum es eigentlich geht, aber Verständliches kann trotzdem falsch sein.

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. What is the benefit to have task 1-3 included in your question? As far as I read you stumble upon 4 only. Maybe leaving one example, e.g. 3 to show a pattern that you understand.

Comment: I think that it should be "Im Gegensatz dazu...", not "Im Gegenteil dazu...".

Comment: "Glas ist [...] einzuschmelzen" würde ich intuitiv erstmal als Aufforderung auffassen? Aber da es um Konnektoren gehen soll, würde ich - wie schon Gustave im Kommentar oben - "Im Gegenteil dazu" statt "Im Gegensatz dazu" als Lösung vermuten.

Comment: Ich vermute in 4 b) den falschen Gegensatz: "Im Gegensatz zu Glas ... sinkt die Qualität ...". Das müsste korrekt heißen: "Im Gegensatz dazu, dass man Glas ..., sinkt die Qualität ...". Aber es ist schon wirklich schwer, auch dadurch, dass selbst der Vergleichssatz ein bisschen schief ist.

Answer (score 1):

a supplement offer to answer 1

1. c) Papier und Pappe sind recycelbar, **weil** sich der Verbrauch an neuem Holz und der Energie und Wassereinsatz bei der Papierproduktion verringern.
   weil = because / but less using of new wood, energy and water ist not the reason for recycling paper.
   I would recommend to use "wobei" (in doing so, in which, whereat) instead of "weil".
   wobei = *Adverb*.
2. see 1st answer, 2nd comment (Masatwwo Jun 27 at 17:02)
3. b) **Indem** weniger Müll auf dem Campus entsteht, gibt es ab sofort in der Cafeteria Pfandbecher für Kaffee zum Mitnehmen.
   I would recommend to use "damit" (so, so that, in order that) instead of "indem".
4. I agree - tricky.
   I don't think, that the correct solution is c, because "Im Gegenteil dazu" is neither a *Konnektor*, nor a *Referenzwort*. Like as @Gustave on Jul 15th I would recommend "Im Gegensatz dazu".
   a further argument: the quality of these German sentences is not the overkill, f.i. question 1, answer b) "... Infolgedessen verringern sich der Verbrauch an neuem Holz und der Energie- und Wassereinsatz bei der Papierproduktion."

- predicate not correct inflected (*flektiert*), because the subject = "der Verbrauch", Singular, 3. Person, maskulin. Correct = "Infolgedessen verringer**t** sich der Verbrauch ..."

But back to answer the question.
I would take
a) Glas kann ohne Qualitätsverluste beliebig oft eingeschmolzen werden. **Dagegen** sinkt die Qualität des recycelten Kunststoffs.
I would recommend to use "hingegen" instead of "dagegen".

because ...

- even though in a lot of German dictionarys *hingegen* (on the other hand, in contrary, in contrast) is listed as synonym for *dagegen* (against it, in contrast), I think, these 2 words cannot be arbitrary replaced in every case. - There is a little difference in sense.
  You may eventually have a look at the examples at duden.de under details of "hingegen" and "dagegen".
- "dagegen" is a *Referenzwort*, an *Adverb*. But the contrast doesn't refer to "eingeschmolzen werden" and "sinken".
- "hingegen" is a *Konnektor*, a *Konjunktion*, concretly a *modale, restriktiv/adversative Konjunktion*.
  see f.i.
  https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konjunktion_(Wortart)#Unterordnende_Konjunktionen_im_Deutschen

... of course I'm not completly sure - I really would be interested in the answer of the teacher ;-)

If something is not clear in my text because of my iffy/lousy English or for further questions, please do not hesitate to ask.

Answer (score -1):

1. Thats correct the "**weil**" make the sentence nonsense.
2. "**benötigte**" is the verb of the main clause, and the past tense doesn't matter, because this sentence is wrong in present as in past.
3. "**Indem**" is the word that makes the sentence wrong, correct. "**Indem**" is a way to say because.
4. "**Im Gegenteil**" is not the wrong one here. But it's a tricky one. It took me a bit to find the wrong word.

if you want to know the explanations just give a comment.

Comment: Yes, please add an explanation to your answer so I can mark it as solved.

Comment: 2) **Als** is the connector. It means **as** or **when** 

The sentence means "**When** glass was created from it's original resources, it consumed less energy than the recycled glass."

Comment: Dang don't found it in 4) anymore. in 1) to 3) all had logic mistakes in it. In 4) all answers were logically correct